# Typescript typeguard boolean results in never

Tags: typescript

I have a variable `topLeft` that's a boolean and it can have types of either `number` or `boolean`. `topLeft` will changed into a number and if it's already a number then increase it by one. I have a typeguard that turns `topLeft` into a number if it was a boolean. But in the else statement, the variable results in `never` type.

```js
type BoxCell = number | boolean;
let topLeft: BoxCell = true;

if (typeof topLeft === 'boolean') {
  topLeft = 1;
} else {
  topLeft += 1; // <--- Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)
}
```

`topLeft` is a fixed value in the code example but what I'm working on, involves the variable could either be a boolean or a number.

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2018",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */,
    "outDir": "./dist" /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */,
    "strict": true /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

Comment: If I change your definition of `topLeft` to something like `let topLeft: BoxCell = Math.random() < 0.5 ? true : 4;`, that error goes away.  The compiler knows that `topLeft` is *definitely* a `boolean` in the example code you gave, so it reduces its type to `never` in the (impossible) case that `typeof topLeft !== "boolean"`.  If you still get the error in your actual code where `topLeft` presumably could be either a `boolean` or a `number`, please post a [mcve] that demonstrates this.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an [open issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20203) for this. You can use the binary infix addition operator instead, to fix this: `topLeft = topLeft + 1`

```
type BoxCell = number | boolean;
let topLeft: BoxCell = true;

if (typeof topLeft === 'boolean') {
  topLeft = 1;
} else {
  topLeft = topLeft + 1;  // <- no error
}
```